# How to keep a JPanel fixed while scrolling in a JScrollPane in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm a Java beginner (1 month experience) but liking it so far !
I need to implement a feature on a Planning application that I didn't create, I need to make the panel containing days stay fixed while scrolling (Excel-like headers).

While searching for answers, I mostly find methods using `JTable` but the problem is that I only use `JPanel` or `MainPanel`, which extends `JPanel`, contained in the `WindowPanel` (`JPanel`) with `TopPanel` (`JPanel`) (not showing in the image which is already fixed).
I'm using the `setColumnHeaderView()` method which seems to be the only one showing results.

```
    //MainWindow
    MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(model);
    mainPanel.init(); //fill the mainPanel
    windowPanel.add(mainPanel);

    JViewport blabla = new JViewport();
    blabla.setPreferredSize(mainPanel.getPreferredSize());
    blabla.setView(mainPanel);
    //JViewport blabla2 = new JViewport();
    //blabla2.setPreferredSize(windowPanel.getPreferredSize());

    scroll = new JScrollPane(windowPanel);
    scroll.setColumnHeaderView(blabla);


    getContentPane().add(scroll);
    this.addMouseListener(new FocusSetterListener());

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
```

With this method, I get the right header but no scrollbar, and the panel below (here the `WindowPanel`) stays just blue.

[image: ResultScreenshot1]

Actually, in place of the `WindowPanel` I need to display the filled `MainPanel`, which is working when I do that:

```
        //MainWindow
    MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(model);
    mainPanel.init(); //fill the mainPanel
    windowPanel.add(mainPanel);

    JViewport blabla = new JViewport();
    blabla.setPreferredSize(mainPanel.getPreferredSize());
    blabla.setView(mainPanel);

    scroll = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
    scroll.setColumnHeaderView(blabla);

    getContentPane().add(scroll);
    this.addMouseListener(new FocusSetterListener());

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
```

But the header stays blue and the Days Header is not fixed, it's just below the header but everything else is loading fine including the scrollbar (not that relevant so not in pictures).
For information, the panel below is formed of customPanels called cellPanels:

[image: Result Screenshot 2]

[image: Result Screenshot 2]

I think I'm close to my goal but I tested many things and nothing fully worked. 
I'm looking for someone to explain me what I'm doing wrong and help me fix it.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

I found an acceptable solution,

I loaded a copy of my MainPanel and hided it behind the real one except for the header and applied a boolean to every features to prevent double actions.
It worked but it was pretty hard to debug because some features were mandatory.

I'm still looking for a better answer because of the unwanted double loading optimization problems but at least it does work right now !